# how can i fetch text box value in string array and print

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

this is my code 1 index print second index showing error `"Index was outside the bounds of the array."` please help what should I do?

```
string[] SName = Request.Form.GetValues("title");
string[] Email = Request.Form.GetValues("fname");

for (int i = 0; i <= SName.Length - 1; i++)
{
     Response.Write(SName[i]);
     Response.Write(Email[i]);
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < SName.Length - 1; i++)`

remove the equal sign on your condition.

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary you get same length for both `SName` and `Email` string arrays.

`Index is out of bound because length are not same`.

Better way is to do it separately:

```
string[] SName = Request.Form.GetValues("title");
string[] Email = Request.Form.GetValues("fname");

for (int i = 0; i < SName.Length; i++)        
   Response.Write(SName[i]);       

for (int i = 0; i < Email.Length; i++)
   Response.Write(Email[i]);
```

If you want to `print one name and email` then use this:

```
 string[] SName = Request.Form.GetValues("title");
 string[] Email = Request.Form.GetValues("fname");
 int iLength = -1; 

 if(SName.Length > Email.Length) 
     iLength = SName.Length;
 else
    iLength = Email.Length;

 for (int i = 0; i < iLength; i++)
 {
     if(i < SName.Length)
        Response.Write(SName[i]);          
     if(i < Email.Length)
        Response.Write(Email[i]);
 }
```

**NOTE**:

If you are not dealing with array of HTML element with same name then you don't have to use `Request.Form.GetValues("title")`. See following example:

```
string SName = Request.Form["title"];
string Email = Request.Form["fname"];

Response.Write(SName + " " + Email);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be.

```
if (SName != null)    
    for (int i = 0; i < SName.Length; i++)
        Response.Write(SName[i]);

if (Email != null)
    for (int i = 0; i < Email.Length; i++)
        Response.Write(Email[i]);
```

The problem is that length of SName and Email are different.

Comment: He is also decreasing `SName.Length` by 1.

Comment: In this case, the length check would not be needed. The for loop won't enter when the length is 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code, which gives the result in a single loop

```
if (SName != null && SName.Length > 0 && Email != null && Email.Length > 0)
{
     for (int i = 0,j=0; i < SName.Length && j<Email.Length; i++,j++)
     {
          Response.Write(SName[i]);
          Response.Write(Email[j]);
     }
}
```